# Problems with extended acl in Packet Tracer several versions

Tags: packet, cisco

when I enter a new acl like this one

```
access-list 101 permit ip 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0
```

but when I look to the running-configuration it appears as

```
access-list 101 permit ip 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

I have tried 3 versions of Packet Tracer. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because ACLs use wildcard masks instead of subnets.

You need to convert your subnet mask `255.255.255.0` into a wildcard mask `0.0.0.255`:

```
Router(config)#access-list 101 permit ip 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.255
```